# unexpected output of the following c program

Tags: c

the following code as expected should accept two char values from user. but it just accepts one value of ch1 and then prints "hello".

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch1, ch2;

    printf("Enter a char: ");
    scanf("%c",&ch1);

    printf("Enter second char: ");
    scanf("%c",&ch2);



    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

it is not accepting the second value for ch2..what can be the possible reason?
As far as i think, it should  accept 2 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just accepts only one char because the the first call to `scanf()` left a newline in the input stream.

You can ignore it with:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch2); // note the leading space.
```

This will ensure the newline from the previous input will be ignored. A white-space in the format string tells `scanf()` to ignore *any* number of white-space characters. You might also want to check the return value of `scanf()` calls in case it failed.

From [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

```
    .     A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline,
          etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of
          white space, including none, in the input.
```